# Haskkor Pin Code get value in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

I'm facing a problem. In my react native app, I have Pin code which I used and installed `@haskkor/react-native-pincode - npm`. The problem is I want to get the value of the register pin code in my mobile app but it seems there's no command in this `npm` to get the registered value because I want to store it together with my google email details through `firestore` or `asyncStorage`. I just want to print the value of registered if `pin is available. I'ts very helpful for me if this solve thanks in advance.

Source : [@haskkor/react-native-pincode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@haskkor/react-native-pincode/v/1.14.0)

```
 import PINCode, {
 hasUserSetPinCode,
 resetPinCodeInternalStates,
 deleteUserPinCode,
} from "@haskkor/react-native-pincode";

 const [PinCodeVisible, setPin] = useState({ PINCodeStatus: "choose", showPinLock: false });


 async function pinCode() {
    const hasPin = await hasUserSetPinCode();
    console.log(hasUserSetPinCode);

    if (!hasPin) {
        console.log("No pin");
        setPin({ PINCodeStatus: "choose", showPinLock: true });
    }
    else if (hasPin) {

        console.log ("PRINT HERE - HOW TO GET THE VALUE OF REGISTERED PIN CODE ---------------------- ");
        setPin({ PINCodeStatus: "enter", showPinLock: true });

        
    }
    else {
        console.log("does not have pin");
        _showChoosePinLock();

    }
}
```

Comment: Someone knows about my problem need help

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the complete component, to save time I hope this snippet solves your problem.

You need to invoke your pinCode function immediately the component loads using either the useEffect hooks or an IIFE.

```
import {useEffect} from 'react'
import PINCode, {
   hasUserSetPinCode,
   deleteUserPinCode,
   resetPinCodeInternalStates,
 } from "@haskkor/react-native-pincode";
    
let example = () => { 

  const [PinCodeVisible, setPin] = useState({ PINCodeStatus: "choose", showPinLock: false });

 useEffect(()=> {
   pinCode()
 },[]);  
 
  //this function returns the password typed by the user for you to save in either firebase or async store
 async function handlePasswordInput(text) {
    console.log('Password entered is:' text)
 }

 //this function checks if the user has existing password
 async function pinCode() {
  const hasPin = await hasUserSetPinCode();
  console.log(hasUserSetPinCode);
        
  if (!hasPin) {

     console.log("No pin");
     setPin({ PINCodeStatus: "choose", showPinLock: true });

  } else if (hasPin) {
        
   console.log ("PRINT HERE - HOW TO GET THE VALUE OF REGISTERED PIN CODE");
   setPin({ PINCodeStatus: "enter", showPinLock: true });
                  
 } else {

   console.log("does not have pin");
   _showChoosePinLock();
        
 }
        
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <PINCode 
       status={'choose'}           
       finishProcess={handlePasswordInput}
    />
  </View>
 )
}
```